# Relation of the upper triangular factor and the original matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose 
$$PA = LU$$
is the LU factorization(exact) of the square real matrix A, L is the unit lower triangular matrix.

Is there a way to determine the relation between the norm of $U$ and the norm of $A$, such as an upper bound for 
$$\frac{||U||}{||A||} \quad or \quad \frac{\kappa(U)}{\kappa(A)}?$$

The only thing I can found is, $L$ is well-conditioned generally but not proven.
Then $$\frac{||U||}{||A||} \approx 1 \quad\frac{\kappa(U)}{\kappa(A)} \approx 1 ?$$
What about $$\frac{\kappa(U^{-T} A)}{\kappa(A)}?$$

Comment: If you choose the norm $\|A\| = \max_{i,j} |A_{ij}|$ then there are contrived examples with $\|A\|=1$ and $\|U\| = 2^{m-1}$ for $m \times m$ matrices.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your reply. Perhaps the upper bound is really large and no point finding it.

Comment: With the above norm, $2^{m-1}$ is an upper bound. But it is large enough to have little value (bad wording!), and in practice not an issue.